# Converting an object/array into JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, extjs4.1

I have an array (it might be an object too, I don't know what I'm talking about):

```
grid.columns[0].text
grid.columns[1].text
grid.columns[2].text
```

And so on. I want to convert it into JSON. I've tried to use `JSON.stringify(grid.columns.text)` but it didn't work: it gives `null`.

Comment: What do you want to convert to JSON? The `grid` object or  `grid.columns` array?

Comment: You have an array (`grid.columns`) whose _elements_ have `.text` properties, while you are trying to stringify a `.text` property on the array itself. It is not clear what you are trying to do, so I cannot suggest how to fix your code.

Comment: @JamesAllardice, _grid column header names_. the `grid` object is very big. the `grid.columns` array.

Comment: As James Allardice said, did you try to convert grid.columns? That is: JSON.stringify(grid.columns);

Comment: @Angel, as I look through `console.log(grid.columns)` I see that the `grid.columns` is very very huge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
JSON.stringify(grid.columns.map(function(item) {
    return item.text;
}));
// ["value of text 0", "value of text 1",...]
```

---

Alternatively

```
JSON.stringify(grid.columns.map(function(item) {
    return {text:item.text};
}));
// [{"text":"value of text 0"},{"text":"value of text 1"},..]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `JSON.stringify(grid.columns.text)` isn't going to work based off your provided structure:

Try the following instead:

```
JSON.stringify(grid.columns);
```

This should produce something like:

```
[
  {"text": "value"},
  {"text": "value2"},
  {"text": "value3"},
  ...
]
```